# Sobolev space-exercice

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^2_+$.
My question is: how we prove that 
if $v \in H^2(\Omega)$ such as $v(x,0)=0$, then $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: Please **do not** deface your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $T:C_0^2(\overline{\mathbb{R}^2_+})\to C_0^1(\mathbb{R})$ by $$(Tu)(x)=u(x,0),\ \forall\ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

By using the calculations in Theorem 4.1. [here](http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/courses/Applied%20Computational%20Methods/ACM2007Chap4.pdf), we have that $$\|Tu\|_{H^1}\le C\|u\|_{H_2},\ \forall\ u\in C_0^2(\overline{\mathbb{R}^2_+}) \tag{1}$$

Moreover, note that $$\frac{d}{dx}(Tu)(x)=T\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u\right)(x)\ \forall u\in C_0^2(\overline{\mathbb{R}^2_+})\tag{2}$$

Now we use the denseness of $C_0^2(\overline{\mathbb{R}^2_+})$ in $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2_+)$, $(1)$, $(2)$ and the continuity of the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ to conclude that

$$\frac{d}{dx}(Tu)(x)=T\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u\right)(x)\ \forall u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^2_+)\tag{3}$$

To conclude, if $v$ satisfies $v(x,0)=0$ then $Tv=0$, hence, by using $(3)$ we conclude that $T\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}v\right)=0$ which is the same to say that $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\in H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^2_+)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understant two points: 1. what's calculs give us t(1)? All the proof of the theorem 4.1? and for the second point, why $T(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}v)=0$ is the same to say that $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \in H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^2_+)$?

Comment: For your first question then answer is yes. Concerning the second question, did you tried to prove it first? $$H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^2_+)=\{u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^2_+):\ Tu=0\}$$